# Prevent multiple login Servlets

Tags: servlets, authentication, duplicates, account

Is there a way to prevent multiple login with the same account using Servlet? A request goes through 2 Filters from a JSP page, the request should be intercepted and inform the user for duplicated login access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with multiple login, always try to use client side and server side **caching**. It not only helps with duplicate request but also handle multiple user access control.